# show image in uiViewController objective-c

Tags: objective-c, for-loop, uiimageview, uiimage, nsarray

I have a UIViewController with 10 IBOutlet images,
I have one image and I want to show it based on my i in for loop
I mean If my i is equal to 3 put img1,img2,img3 in the view

here is my code,
my problem is that I can not show it,
would you please let me know what is the problem,Thanks in advance!

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *img1;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *img2;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *img3;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *img4;



- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
[super viewDidAppear:YES];

NSLog(@"Card description : %@", [_card description]);

int stampNumber = [_card.stampNumber intValue];

int i = 0;
UIImage *stampIMG = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.jpg"];

NSLog(@"StampNumber  :  %i", stampNumber);
for (i = 0; i < stampNumber; i++) {
    NSLog(@"i = %i", i);
    switch (i)
    {
        case 0:
            [_img1 setImage:stampIMG];
            NSLog (@"one");
            break;
        case 1:
            [_img2 setImage:stampIMG];
            NSLog (@"two");
            break;
        case 2:
            [_img3 setImage:stampIMG];
            NSLog (@"three");
            break;
        case 3:
            [_img4 setImage:stampIMG];
            NSLog (@"four");
            break;
        case 4:
            [_img5 setImage:stampIMG];
            NSLog (@"five");
            break;
        case 5:
            [_img6 setImage:stampIMG];
            NSLog (@"six");
            break;
        case 6:
            [_img7 setImage:stampIMG];
            NSLog (@"seven");
            break;
        case 7:
            [_img8 setImage:stampIMG];
            NSLog (@"eight");
            break;
        case 8:
            [_img9 setImage:stampIMG];
            NSLog (@"nine");
            break;
        case 9:
            [_img10 setImage:stampIMG];
            NSLog (@"ten");
            break;
        default:
            NSLog (@"test");
            break;
    }
        }
```

}

Here is my log :

```
StampNumber  :  5
2013-03-18 14:14:31.  i = 0
2013-03-18 14:14:31.  one
2013-03-18 14:14:31.  i = 1
2013-03-18 14:14:31.  two
2013-03-18 14:14:31.  i = 2
2013-03-18 14:14:31.  three
2013-03-18 14:14:31.  i = 3
2013-03-18 14:14:31.  four
2013-03-18 14:14:31.  i = 4
2013-03-18 14:14:31.  five
```

Comment: Use a switch statement! It will facilitate your life!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use:

```
UIImage *stampIMG = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1"];
```

file extensions are not given in `imageNamed:`

Comment: still nothing appear in my view

Comment: nslog stampIMG and tell what there?

Comment: Update question check please

Comment: @AnoopVaidya, this will not fix the problem. You can give file extensions in imageNamed.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some problems with your code:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
[super viewDidAppear:YES];

NSLog(@"Card description : %@", [_card description]);

int stampNumber = [_card.stampNumber intValue];

int i = 0;

/* Like Anoop pointed out, you do need an extension for the image */
UIImage *stampIMG = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1"];

NSLog(@"StampNumber  :  %i", stampNumber);
for (i = 0; i < stampNumber; i++) {
    NSLog(@"i = %i", i);

/* One more point here is although this is easy for 10 images to do a manual check and update (and efficient in this case), its better to use an IBOutletCollection with tag indication if you need.
*/
    switch (i)
    {
        case 0:
            [_img1 setImage:stampIMG];
            NSLog (@"one");
            break;
        case 1:
            [_img2 setImage:stampIMG];
            NSLog (@"two");
            break;
        case 2:
            [_img3 setImage:stampIMG];
            NSLog (@"three");
            break;
        case 3:
            [_img4 setImage:stampIMG];
            NSLog (@"four");
            break;
        case 4:
            [_img5 setImage:stampIMG];
            NSLog (@"five");
            break;
        case 5:
            [_img6 setImage:stampIMG];
            NSLog (@"six");
            break;
        case 6:
            [_img7 setImage:stampIMG];
            NSLog (@"seven");
            break;
        case 7:
            [_img8 setImage:stampIMG];
            NSLog (@"eight");
            break;
        case 8:
            [_img9 setImage:stampIMG];
            NSLog (@"nine");
            break;
        case 9:
            [_img10 setImage:stampIMG];
            NSLog (@"ten");
            break;
        default:
            NSLog (@"test");
            break;
    }
        }


/*
are the _imgi IBOutlets reference outlets from either your story board or xib file?
if so you do not need to add these as subviews.
If not so, then these are supposed to be instantiated in your code and they need to be UIImageView's rather than IBOutlets. IBOutlets are nothing but void type casts just for the compilers efficiency.
*/

    [self.view addSubview:_img1];
    [self.view addSubview:_img2];
    [self.view addSubview:_img3];
    [self.view addSubview:_img4];
    [self.view addSubview:_img5];
    [self.view addSubview:_img6];
    [self.view addSubview:_img7];
    [self.view addSubview:_img8];
    [self.view addSubview:_img9];
    [self.view addSubview:_img10];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is elsewhere in your code.

> I have a UIViewController with 10 IBOutlet images

You have declared ten IBOutlet image *Views* - like this?

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *img1;
```

etc...?

Then... you have linked those declarations to ten imageViews in your storyboard/xib?

If so... why are you doing this:

```
[self.view addSubview:_img1];
[self.view addSubview:_img2];
[self.view addSubview:_img3];
```

the subviews are already added in the storyboard.

If you have NOT added the views yet, then this is where your problem lies.

For example if you alloc/init each view, for example:

```
   self.img1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRect){10,10,50,50}];
```

You won't see any of your images, becuase your IBOutlet is a WEAK property (it assumes that the object already exists in the storyboard so doesn't claim ownership).

Check this and sort it out...

- add the imageViews in your storyboard
- link them to your IBOutlets
- don't `addSubview`

Then it should work

Alternatively

- don't add the subViews in your storyboard
- declare them as STRONG (non-IBOutlet) properties

  ```
  @property (strong, nonatomic) UIImageView *img1;
  ```
- alloc/init them in code
- `addSubview`

That should work also

Comment: I update my question, my picture shows when I change the orientation

Comment: @adam, I don't see a picture  and your question isn't about orientation! If it is still not working then  try  `NSLog (@"_img1.image");` instead of `NSLog (@"one");` etc  to see if the imageView is getting the image. Also check you have wired up your IBOutlets to the imageView objects in the storyboard. The IBOutlets should be WEAK not STRONG.